# My Facebook App can no longer access user profile pictures

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API (v8.0) endpoint {user-id}/picture with a valid user access token in the querystring. This used to retrieve the profile picture, but as of 6/28 I began receiving the following error:

"Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXXXXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation." (where 'XXXXXX' is a valid user ID from Facebook).

Is anyone else seeing this? Any ideas? I am able to access graph.facebook.com/me using the same access_token parameter and it's valid.

Comment: Might be related to https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/865886727349561/

Comment: @CBroe, that is certainly relevant. Sucks quite royally too.